# Нужна ли запятая после слов "покупая продукцию"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Нужна ли запятая перед Вы в предложение ниже?

> Покупая продукцию Б вы получаете гарантированный подарок.

Answer (score 2):

**Покупая продукцию Б, вы получаете гарантированный подарок.**

Обособление обстоятельства, выраженного деепричастным оборотом.

Сравнить: Если вы покупаете продукцию Б, то получаете гарантированный подарок.

Answer (score 2):

Получаете (что делая?) **покупая продукцию Б.**
Это [**деепричастный оборот**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/), который требует обособления (запятая перед ВЫ нужна).

Вот похожие предложения.
Покупая продукцию "АтАг", Вы получаете качественный товар по оптимальной цене.
Покупая продукцию у нас, Вы получаете надежную гарантию и сервисное обслуживание без посредников...